# ASP.NET Core MVC - Ways to show industrial process workflow in a graphical representation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

We are in the process of converting a huge monolithic WPF application to an MVC application. This application has some graphics which show the progress of a particular industrial process using circles, rectangles, arrows, and some customized design shapes. These elements are managed based on some events either by manual interaction or by business logic. 
Currently, these graphics are hosted in an ASP.net application using XBAP. Since it has a dependency on the IE browser, we want to move to a new technology to support this feature in other browsers.

Are there any tools and libraries (either paid or free) available to achieve this easily. Basically, we want to drag and drop certain shapes and save them separately and load them on demand and manipulate based on some events. 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is Genuine but asking recommendations and recommending to third-party(paid or free) controls attracts a lot of heat on question & answers so I am avoiding some of good licensed controls, try searching for chart controls for asp.net mvc, there are many out-of-box solution based on your needs.

If you want custom controls that can be done in canvas, svg, HTML5 easily.
I loved d3 js https://d3js.org/ which is open source, lightweight ,highly scalable, cross browser compatibility, can render very big data-sets with minimal memory and very easy to learn & implement

Tutorial to start with is here https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Some opensource examples of d3.js are available here https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery